# How to retry singe deferred loader value in react router dom?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I would like to retry differed request made from within the react router loader.

**Use case**
I have two differed requests and I would like to retry/reload them selectively from the user interface, without reloading the whole page and making both of requests again.

**Code**

```
export const rootLoader = async () => {
  const position = getPosition();
  return defer({
    currentWeather: position
      .then((position) => position.coords)
      .then((cords) =>
        fetch(
          `someApi`
        )
      )
      .then((response) => {
        if (response.ok) {
          return response.json();
        }
        console.log("response not ok");
        throw new Error(
          "Seems like we have some troubles retrieving data at this moment"
        );
      })
      .catch((error) => console.log(error.message)),

    forecastWeather: position
      .then((position) => position.coords)
      .then((cords) =>
        fetch(
          `someApi`
        ).then((response) => {
          if (response.ok) {
            return response.json();
          }
          throw new Error(
            "Seems like we have some troubles retrieving data at this moment"
          );
        })
      ),
  });
};
```

Error handeling and UI

```
const Root = () => {
  const data = useLoaderData();

  return (
    <div>
      <React.Suspense fallback={<SkeletonWeather />}>
        <Await resolve={data.currentWeather} errorElement={<ErrorMsg />}>
          {(currentWeather) => (
            <LocationWeatherView weatherData={currentWeather} />
          )}
        </Await>
      </React.Suspense>

      <React.Suspense fallback={<SkeletonForecast />}>
        <Await resolve={data.forecastWeather} errorElement={<ErrorMsg />}>
          {(forecastWeather) => <Forecast forecastData={forecastWeather} />}
        </Await>
      </React.Suspense>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Error component, at the moment it is reloading the whole loader as I am triggering manual page refresh.

```
const ErrorMsg = () => {
  const error = useAsyncError();

  return (
    <div>
      <button
        onClick={() => window.location.reload()}
      >
        Try Again
      </button>
      {error.message}
    </div>
  );
};
```